# How to test a man in the middle HTTPS proxy?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

We are looking for guidelines for testing a new product that works as a "man in the middle" proxy, and intercept HTTPS traffic.

This system needs to act as a standard browsers and block any attempt to access a site with invalid certificate.

We thought about testing the following scenarios:

- Expired certificate
- A certificate that was issues for a future date
- The requested hostname does not match the certificate hostname
- The certificate is not signed by a root CA

My questions are:

1. What other certificates scenario should we test?
2. Which tools should we use to generate those "invalid" certificates?
3. Do you know of any open source project (maybe a browser or proxy) that has a set of unit tests that we can learn from?

Thanks.

Comment: You're creating a man-in-the-middle proxy, and trying to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks? I'm curious to see what the application is.

Comment: @Stefan Mai: Content inspection is one application that driving the development of SSL MiTM proxies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure of certificate validation is completely described in the corresponding RFCs (3280, 2560 etc.) and you don't need to invent any "scenarios".

For generation of certificates including invalid ones you can use our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-pki.php) components (trial mode will be enough).

Comment: Do you know what are the relevant sections in the RFCs for the required scenarios?

Comment: @NTB When you follow the validation procedures, you don't need scenarios. You just implement the procedure step by step. It's described in details in section 6 of RFC 3280. The link has been updated, thank you

Comment: Thank you for enriching my knowledge. Is it possible to sign certificates with a root CA using SecureBlackbox?

Comment: @NTB Yes, SecureBlackbox offers full scope of PKI operations including certificate generation, signing and validation (our validator performs all required checks except policy and path constraint checks, and you can extend the validator to perform those checks in your code).